# How to produce sum of each column in sql?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am trying to do column wise addition in Gridview but couldn't.

like i am filling gridview from store procedure which gives these values .

```
DateTime 10Quantity 20Quantity 30Quantity 10Amount 20Amount 30Amount GrandTotal
03/10/2015  792      0           594        7920        0     17820   25740
03/10/2015  332      3           194        9990        0     28220   38739
```

Expected:

```
DateTime 10Quantity 20Quantity 30Quantity 10Amount 20Amount 30Amount GrandTotal
03/10/2015  792      0           594        7920        0     17820   25740
03/10/2015  332      3           194        9990        0     28220   38739
Totals      1124     3           788        17910       0     46040   64479
```

i want a new row 'Totals' which should represent total for each column i.e. addition.

Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewDenominationsWiseTransactions" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        ShowFooter="True" OnRowDataBound="GridViewDenominationsWiseTransactions_RowDataBound"  CssClass="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="DateTime" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm}" HtmlEncode="false"  ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                                <ItemStyle Width="11%" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                           <%-- <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Conductor Name" DataField="ConductorName" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                                <ItemStyle Width="8%"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>--%>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="10 Quantity" DataField="10Quantity" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                                <ItemStyle Width="8%" CssClass="visible-desktop"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="20 Quantity" DataField="20Quantity" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                                <ItemStyle Width="8%" CssClass="visible-desktop"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="30 Quantity" DataField="30Quantity" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                                <ItemStyle Width="8%" CssClass="visible-desktop"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="10 Amount" DataField="10Amount" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                                <ItemStyle Width="8%" CssClass="visible-desktop"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="20 Amount" DataField="20Amount" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                                <ItemStyle Width="8%" CssClass="visible-desktop"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="30 Amount" DataField="30Amount" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                                <ItemStyle Width="8%" CssClass="visible-desktop"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="GrandTotal" DataField="GrandTotal" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                                <ItemStyle Width="13%" CssClass="visible-desktop"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

SP;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReportDenominationWiseTransaction] '03-10-2015', '03-10-2015'
@FromDate date,
@ToDate date
AS
    BEGIN   
        with myquery ([DateTime],amount,Quantity) 
        as
        (
            select  Convert(varchar(20),serverdatetime,101) 'DateTime',amount,1 'Quantity'
                 from tickets
                 WHERE CONVERT(DATE,ServerDateTime) BETWEEN @FromDate and @ToDate
        )
        select *, 10 * c.[10Quantity] '10Amount',20 * c.[20Quantity] '20Amount',30 * c.[30Quantity] '30Amount',((10 * c.[10Quantity])+(20 * c.[20Quantity])+(30 * c.[30Quantity]))'GrandTotal' from (
        SELECT DateTime,[10] AS '10Quantity', [20] AS '20Quantity', [30] AS '30Quantity'
        FROM 
        (SELECT [DateTime], amount,quantity
        FROM myquery) p
        PIVOT
        (
        COUNT ([Quantity])
        FOR [Amount] IN
        ( [10], [20], [30])
        ) AS pvt
        ) as c
    END
```

i must do it from front end i.e. gridview

Comment: Can you add the expected result?

Comment: check it being added

Answer (score 0):

Use the RowDataBound event handler to evaluate data (sum columns) when they are added to the GridView.

And add a footer to show the totals.

Take a look at this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310552.aspx
STEP 3: solution 2.
That is how you use an eventhandler to run totals in a GridView.

Comment: sorry didn't get u, i don't understand

Comment: @AamirShah, one can't be clear than this. The link actually shows the complete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can find the `SUM` of each column by `sql` itself using `GROUPING SETS`.

**Query**

```
SELECT [DateTime],
SUM([10Quantity]) AS [10Quantity],
SUM([20Quantity]) AS [20Quantity],
SUM([30Quantity]) AS [30Quantity],
SUM([10Amount]) AS [10Amount],
SUM([20Amount]) AS [20Amount],
SUM([30Amount]) AS [30Amount],
SUM([GrandTotal]) AS [GrandTotal]
FROM table_name
GROUP BY 
GROUPING SETS(([DateTime],[10Quantity],[20Quantity],
[30Quantity],[10Amount],[20Amount],[30Amount],[GrandTotal]),());
```