# Why my result set doesn't produce sum for each column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-ce

I have been working on sql query and tried to produce a new row which show show sum of each column below it.

I am getting this right now

```
DateTime 10Quantity 20Quantity 30Quantity 10Amount 20Amount 30Amount GrandTotal
03/10/2015  792      0           594        7920        0     17820   25740
03/10/2015  332      3           194        9990        0     28220   38739
```

but i want this as an output:

```
DateTime 10Quantity 20Quantity 30Quantity 10Amount 20Amount 30Amount GrandTotal
03/10/2015  792      0           594        7920        0     17820   25740
03/10/2015  332      3           194        9990        0     28220   38739
Totals      1124     3           788        17910       0     46040   64479
```

SP: Even i tried GROUPING SETS but failed to achieve. Please help.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReportDenominationWiseTransaction] '03-10-2015', '03-10-2015'
    @FromDate date,
    @ToDate date
    AS
        BEGIN   
            with myquery ([DateTime],amount,Quantity) 
            as
            (
                select  Convert(varchar(20),serverdatetime,101) 'DateTime',amount,1 'Quantity'
                     from tickets
                     WHERE CONVERT(DATE,ServerDateTime) BETWEEN @FromDate and @ToDate
            )
            select *, 10 * c.[10Quantity] '10Amount',20 * c.[20Quantity] '20Amount',30 * c.[30Quantity] '30Amount',((10 * c.[10Quantity])+(20 * c.[20Quantity])+(30 * c.[30Quantity]))'GrandTotal' from (
            SELECT DateTime,[10] AS '10Quantity', [20] AS '20Quantity', [30] AS '30Quantity'
            FROM 
            (SELECT [DateTime], amount,quantity
            FROM myquery) p
            PIVOT
            (
            COUNT ([Quantity])
            FOR [Amount] IN
            ( [10], [20], [30])
            ) AS pvt
            ) as c
        END
```

Comment: :[Your previous question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981125/why-my-result-set-doesnt-produce-sum-for-each-column). Use sql query  `GROUPING SETS` and bind that result to the `GridView`. [My previous answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963625/how-to-produce-sum-of-each-column-in-sql/28964424#28964424).

Comment: sir i tried grouping sets but all got messed up, nothing worked, may be i merged that wrongly, can u help me ?

Comment: Why not use UNION ALL? So, just produce the first result table (as you have it already and then add with UNION ALL the sum to the bottom.

Comment: COMPUTE SUM(SubTotal), SUM(TotalDue);

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpRes
(
 DateTime varchar(50),
10Quantity varchar(50),
20Quantity varchar(50),
10Quantity varchar(50),
10Quantity varchar(50),
10Amount  varchar(50),
20Amount varchar(50),
30Amount varchar(50),
GrandTotal varcahr(50)
)

INSERT INTO #tmpRes(col1,col2,....)
SELECT  cols1,col2,..
FROM  my_table

INSERT INTO #tmpRes(col1,col2,....)
SELECT  'Totals',sum(10Quantity ),sum(20Quantity ).......
FROM  my_table


select * from #tmpRes
```